# RangeOfString crash on not finding result iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have string from `JSON` that sometimes looks like this @"2, 18, 27, 29" called mayString. Other times this string will just be @"2" (One number and no comma separation)

I want to test if the string contains the comma using the below code:

```
NSRange range = [mayString rangeOfString:@","];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog (@"Substring found at: %d", range.location);
        }

        else{

            NSLog (@"Substring not found");
        }
```

It works fine when the string does contain a comma separation but crashes when there isn't a comma I would expect the log to say `"Substring not found"?` But I get `[__NSCFNumber rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d533500`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code...as Marcin is right...

```
NSRange range = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mayString] rangeOfString:@","];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog (@"Substring found at: %d", range.location);
        }

        else{

            NSLog (@"Substring not found");
        }
```

Comment: Yep this worked thats a bit rubbish that JSON would do that I would have never figured it did that. I would expect if I declare and want a string I get a string not a number...but I am always learning. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your "string" is actually an instance of NSNumber.

Comment: its defo a string (nonatomic, strong)NSString *mayString;

Comment: Your property may be defined as NSString, but when you convert your JSON data to Foundation objects, the string without commas is interpreted as a number.

Comment: Ok so when I have multiple values like @"2, 3, 4, 5" this is interpreted as a string but single like this @"2" is being read as a number?

Comment: That is correct. I think you need to have a string like @"\"2\"" to make sure it is interpreted as a string and not a number.

Answer (score 4):

Since JSON is untyped, the parser tries to figure out what's inside the string. When the string looks like a number, say, `@"2"`, JSON gives you back an `NSNumber` object, not an `NSString`. You can assign it to `NSString *` variable, and Objective C compiler would not complain, but the value inside would remain `NSNumber`.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
id myObject = ... // Instead of MSString *myString

if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog (@"Object is not a string");
} else if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSRange range = [mayString rangeOfString:@","];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog (@"Substring found at: %d", range.location);
    } else{
        NSLog (@"Substring not found");
    }
}
```

You can also force it into a string, like this:

```
myString = [myString description]; // Not recommended
```

Even if `myString` was `NSNumber` before the assignment above, it will be an `NSString` after it, regardless of its initial type. However, keeping the original type is usually a better approach.

Comment: Surely not when the its declared as a string and looks like a string others the succesful find of the , would not be found other times no?

Comment: @AlexMcPherson What it's declared is of no interest to the compiler. Objective C is not a strongly typed language, you can assign a `NSNumber` to `NSString`, and the compiler would not care. JSON parser will return a string when the data does not look like a number.

Comment: great thanks for the explanation thats cool! I upvoted you too.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `description` method - it's format is undocumented and it's not guaranteed to return same values in future versions. `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", myString]` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your value in JSON has just one number, NSJSONSerializer always converting it to NSNumber. So your NSString actually NSNumber. You can check it with isKindOfClass:

```
if([mayString isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]) {
   // do something
}
```

**EDIT:** sorry duplicate answer, my skill of writing not so good